# Why the output of write function precedes the output of printf function?

Tags: c, printf, output, unistd.h

I was trying to Implement my own printf function and I discovered this strange behavior, when you try to print something using `printf()` and after it you try to print something else using `write()`, the output of `write()` is printed before the output of `printf()`!

As you can see in the example below :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
     printf(" hello world ");
     write(1, "what am doing here", 18);

     return (0);
}
```

and this is the output of the above code :

`"what am doing here hello world "`

## #edit

After I read the answer on the other question I found that

> printf is buffered and write is not.

> For output to a terminal, the C stdio system has a feature that it flushes the buffers whenever it sees a newline '\n'. For more about stdio buffering look at the documentation for setvbuf.a

but in my case there is no new line `'\n'` in `printf()` so that's why the output of `write()` precedes the output of `printf()`.

for example if you use the same code above but with adding `\n` to `printf()` the output will change and the output of printf will be the first.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
     printf(" hello world\n");  //adding \n
     write(1, "what am doing here", 18);

     return (0);
}
```

the output this time is different :

`" hello world what am doing here"`

*hint : this output from online compilers but with the terminal that I'm using, it's output doesn't change and the output of `write()` still printed before the output of `printf()`*

correct me if I am wrong.